# Python matplotlib animation randomly jumping to initial position

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I'm adapting code from [this matplotlib example](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.1/examples/animation/simple_3danim.html) but am finding that within my animation each particle seems to jump back to it's initial position, but not all at the same time? I can't figure out why this would be the case (am I inputting the data correctly?).

I have a program simulating test particles orbiting a central mass. The program outputs data in blocks separated by a new line. Each block consists of a new line for each particle, and each line has 3 numbers, 1 for each dimension.

Here's the code in question:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import csv

#read in data
with open('tmpfile', 'rb') as csvfile: 
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    data = np.array([[float(field) for field in row]
                        for row in filter(lambda x: x != [], reader)])
print(data.shape)
data = data.reshape((21, -1, 3)).swapaxes(1,2)
print(data.shape)


def update_points(num, dataPoints, points) :
    for point, data in zip(points, dataPoints) :
        point.set_data(data[0:2, num-1:num])
        point.set_3d_properties(data[2,num-1:num])
    return points

#prepare plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)

points = [ax.plot(dat[0, 0:1], dat[1, 0:1], dat[2, 0:1], c='b', marker='o')[0] for dat in data]

# Set the axes properties
ax.view_init(90, 90)

ax.set_xlim3d([-8.0, 8.0])
ax.set_xlabel('X')

ax.set_ylim3d([-8.0, 8.0])
ax.set_ylabel('Y')

ax.set_zlim3d([-1.0, 1.0])
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

#Create the Animation object
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_points, 101, fargs=(data, points), 
                                   interval=500, blit=False)

plt.show()
```

And here's an example of the output file format (for 21 particles and 2 time steps, [link to full file with all 100 timesteps](https://www.dropbox.com/s/buv2ocqjblq7zty/tmpfile?dl=0)):

```
0   0   0
1.954   -0.4259 0
0.7562  -1.852  0
2.308   1.917   0
-1.032  -2.817  0
2.001   2.235   0
3.813   1.208   0
-1.888  3.526   0
2.298   -3.274  0
2.556   3.077   0
-4.664  1.802   0
2.719   4.196   0
-3.991  3.012   0
-4.018  2.976   0
4.398   -2.379  0
3.924   -4.539  0
-1.954  -5.673  0
-2.751  5.332   0
3.87    4.585   0
5.725   -1.796  0
5.369   -2.678  0

0   0   0
1.956   -0.419  0
0.7627  -1.849  0
2.304   1.922   0
-1.026  -2.819  0
1.996   2.239   0
3.812   1.212   0
-1.892  3.524   0
2.302   -3.271  0
2.553   3.08    0
-4.666  1.798   0
2.715   4.198   0
-3.994  3.008   0
-4.02   2.973   0
4.4 -2.375  0
3.927   -4.536  0
-1.95   -5.674  0
-2.755  5.33    0
3.867   4.588   0
5.726   -1.792  0
5.371   -2.674  0
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider a smaller example with 2 timesteps and 3 particles:

```
In [175]: data = np.arange(6*3).reshape(6,3); data

Out[175]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17]])
```

If we use `data.reshape(3, -1, 3).swapaxes(1, 2)` then we obtain

```
In [176]: data.reshape(3, -1, 3).swapaxes(1, 2)
Out[176]: 
array([[[ 0,  3],
        [ 1,  4],
        [ 2,  5]],

       [[ 6,  9],
        [ 7, 10],
        [ 8, 11]],

       [[12, 15],
        [13, 16],
        [14, 17]]])
```

Notice that the first particle's positions become [0,1,2] and [3,4,5]. 
But we want the first particle's positions to be [0,1,2] and [9,10,11].

So instead use

```
In [177]: data.reshape((-1, 3, 3)).transpose([1, 2, 0])
Out[177]: 
array([[[ 0,  9],
        [ 1, 10],
        [ 2, 11]],

       [[ 3, 12],
        [ 4, 13],
        [ 5, 14]],

       [[ 6, 15],
        [ 7, 16],
        [ 8, 17]]])
```

---

Therefore, change

```
data = data.reshape((21, -1, 3)).swapaxes(1,2)
```

to

```
data = data.reshape((-1, 21, 3)).transpose([1, 2, 0])
```

Comment: I had had some issues getting the data into the correct shape but hadn't even thought to consider the skip in data between time steps. This solved all my issues, thanks so much!